# ERROR: gcloud crashed (ConnectionError): HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443):

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have been using gcloud cli for last 3months on my system, but now I start facing this error while authenticating with `gcloud auth login` or `gcloud init --console-only`.

After debugging it, I see some issue with the DNS resolution for `oauth2.googleapis.com`

[image]

Below is the result when trying to ping oauth2.googleapis.com:

[image]

PING dotblocking.dummy (13.127.247.216): 56 data bytes (My ISP seems to redirecting it to dotblocking.dummy)
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1

Comment: am also facing the same issue for more than past 48 hrs. Did you able to overcome this with any workaround.

Comment: Hi @shaishaw, can you confirm if the issue has been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you use Airtel broadband. Airtel ISP is the problem. Because of the recent outage issue they had last week. Use CloudFlare or VPN to resolve the issue.

Reference

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836901/gcp-cloud-sql-proxy-times-out-connectex

Answer (score 0):

Change you DNS servers to Google ones.
Clear your DNS cache first